# Как получать id последнего зарегистрированного в вк пользователя в данный момент

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как получать id самого последнего зарегистрированного в вк пользователя средствами PHP? id должен быть самым новым на момент отправки запроса на сайте. Искал что-то из этой оперы в VK API, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Зачем такое нужно, если не секрет?

Comment: Что-то вроде инфодоски на тематическом ресурсе про VK API.

Answer (score 3):

Такой API вы врятли найдете, используйте каталог пользователей ВК:
    https://vk.com/catalog.php
и парсите последние ссылки в списках, пока не получите ссылку пользователя.

Comment: отсортируйте по дате регистрации в поиске людей с пустым фильтром